# Handling Parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

How to validate parameter passed to the controller from view. The following is my view file.

index.html.erb:

```
<html>
<body>
    <center> <h1> Login form </h1> </center>
    <form action='/login/auth' method='GET'>
        Name: <input type="text" name="username" width=20>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" width=20>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is the view file rendered in client side when the client calls '/login' controller. So, once the value is filled and
press the submit button, the datas are passed to '/login/auth' action. With in auth method how to handle the data which is passed from
client side. My controller file is,

login_controller.rb:

```
ass LoginController < ApplicationController
  def auth

  end
end
```

Comment: request params are available via `params` method from within a controller action. `params[:username]`, etc.

Comment: Validate against what? Do you have a method to validate it? Or do you just want to know how to read the params send to the controller? You find them in `params[:username]` and `params[:password]`.

Comment: Although for implementing authentication, you should take a battle-tested solution rather than rolling your own. For example, `devise` is a very popular choice.

Comment: What is wrong with Rails' `has_secure_password`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present? 
  #do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the **"username"** and **"password"** parameters from **params[:username]** and **params[:password]**.

For easy and secure authentication process you can use ***"devise"*** gem which is widely used for authentication. It's easy to configure and provides the login and signup view pages by default.

URL to follow https://github.com/plataformatec/devise